# Postgres SQL group by query that joins and filters on grouping column

Tags: sql, postgresql

The underlying problem is that I have vendor invoices, where each vendor belongs to an organization, and each organization has a set of "excluded vendor roles."

I want to sum and group the invoice charges by vendor, WITHOUT including the charges of vendors whose roles are "excluded."

So if we have the following tables:

`excluded roles`

```
|role_id|org_id|
|      1|     1|
|      2|     2|
```

`vendors`

```
|vendor_id|org_id|
|     v1.1|     1|
|     v1.2|     1|
|     v2.1|     2|
|     v2.2|     2|
```

and this table for `charges`:

```
|vendor_id|charge|role|
|     v1.1|     3|   1|
|     v1.1|     9|   2|
|     v1.2|     4|   1|
|     v1.2|    10|   2|
|     v2.1|     5|   1|
|     v2.2|     6|   2|
|     v2.1|     7|   1|
```

The result should be

```
| group_by(vendor_id)| sum(charges) |
|                v1.1|            9 |
|                v1.2|           10 |
|                v2.1|           12 |
```

Can I do this in Postgres without writing a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you basically want `not exists`:

```
select vendor_id, sum(c.charges)
from charges c join
     vendors v
     using (vendor_id)
where not exists (select 1
                  from excluded e
                  where e.role_id = c.role and e.org_id = v.org_id
                 )
group by vendor_id;
```

In your data, vendors can only be in one org.  If vendors can be in multiple orgs, then moving the `join` to the subquery is better:

```
select vendor_id, sum(c.charges)
from charges c
where not exists (select 1
                  from excluded e join
                       vendors v
                       using (ord_id)
                  where e.role_id = c.role and
                        v.vendor_id = c.vendor_id
                 )
group by vendor_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach, without subquery:

```
SELECT v.vendor_id, sum(c.charge)
FROM charges c
LEFT JOIN vendors v ON v.vendor_id = c.vendor_id
LEFT JOIN excluded_roles r ON r.role_id = c.role AND r.org_id = v.org_id
WHERE r.role_id IS NULL
GROUP BY v.vendor_id;
```

---

Step by step:

```
-- Get vendors with their roles and org_ids
SELECT *
FROM charges c
LEFT JOIN vendors v ON v.vendor_id = c.vendor_id;
```

```
|vendor_id|charge|role|vendor_id|org_id|
|---------|------|----|---------|------|
|v1_1     |3     |1   |v1_1     |1     |
|v1_1     |9     |2   |v1_1     |1     |
|v1_2     |4     |1   |v1_2     |1     |
|v1_2     |10    |2   |v1_2     |1     |
|v2_1     |5     |1   |v2_1     |2     |
|v2_1     |7     |1   |v2_1     |2     |
|v2_2     |6     |2   |v2_2     |2     |
```

```
-- Join with the excluded_roles
SELECT v.vendor_id, sum(c.charge)
FROM charges c
LEFT JOIN vendors v ON v.vendor_id = c.vendor_id
LEFT JOIN excluded_roles r ON r.role_id = c.role AND r.org_id = v.org_id;
```

```
|vendor_id|charge|role|vendor_id|org_id|role_id|org_id|
|---------|------|----|---------|------|-------|------|
|v1_2     |4     |1   |v1_2     |1     |1      |1     |
|v1_1     |3     |1   |v1_1     |1     |1      |1     |
|v2_1     |5     |1   |v2_1     |2     |       |      |
|v2_1     |7     |1   |v2_1     |2     |       |      |
|v1_2     |10    |2   |v1_2     |1     |       |      |
|v1_1     |9     |2   |v1_1     |1     |       |      |
|v2_2     |6     |2   |v2_2     |2     |2      |2     |
```

```
-- Remove the roles existing in the excluded_roles
SELECT *
FROM charges c
LEFT JOIN vendors v ON v.vendor_id = c.vendor_id
LEFT JOIN excluded_roles r ON r.role_id = c.role AND r.org_id = v.org_id
WHERE r.role_id IS NULL;
```

```
|vendor_id|charge|role|vendor_id|org_id|role_id|org_id|
|---------|------|----|---------|------|-------|------|
|v2_1     |5     |1   |v2_1     |2     |       |      |
|v2_1     |7     |1   |v2_1     |2     |       |      |
|v1_2     |10    |2   |v1_2     |1     |       |      |
|v1_1     |9     |2   |v1_1     |1     |       |      |
```

```
-- Aggregate
SELECT v.vendor_id, sum(c.charge)
FROM charges c
LEFT JOIN vendors v ON v.vendor_id = c.vendor_id
LEFT JOIN excluded_roles r ON r.role_id = c.role AND r.org_id = v.org_id
WHERE r.role_id IS NULL
GROUP BY v.vendor_id;
```

```
|vendor_id|sum|
|---------|---|
|v2_1     |12 |
|v1_2     |10 |
|v1_1     |9  |
```